# Wouldn't it be nice if the Question form accorded with the forum scope?

Tags: bug

https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic says

Mathematica Stack Exchange is for users of the software Mathematica developed by Wolfram Research, as well as related products like gridMathematica, Wolfram Workbench, Player (Pro), and the CDF Player.

EDIT: and https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour says

Mathematica® Stack Exchange is a question and answer site for users of Wolfram Mathematica and the Wolfram Language.

but https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/ask says

What's your Mathematica question? Be specific. 
Is your question about Mathematica?

EDIT: screenshot https://i.stack.imgur.com/PN9yc.png

Comment: The reason for this is because the term "Mathematica" used to refer both to the software and to the language. Now "What's your Mathematica question? Be specific. Is your question about Mathematica?" should probably read "What's your Wolfram System/Language question? Be specific. Is your question about the Wolfram Language or a Wolfram System?" for proper accuracy.

Comment: @PatrickStevens FYI: I am offended by the "rebranding" to "Wolfram System" shortly after the death of Steve Jobs who provided the original name *Mathematica*.  I will strongly resist any attempt to "rebrand" this site in that fashion.

Comment: I'm no Jobs fan myself, but I do not have much love for what they seem to be calling it these days. I might compromise with "Wolfram Mathematica", if only to stave off the hordes that keep conflating this site with math.SE, but otherwise, I'm with Wizard on that one.

Comment: Oh, I also detest the names "Wolfram Language", "Wolfram System" etc, and I always call it Mathematica except in contexts like this where there is the slight potential for confusion. I can understand their desire to have a different name, though, now that they're branching out into the WPC etc. I was a fan of Matica, back when they asked for ideas about the name change (as if they ever were going to name it anything other than "Wolfram Language").

Comment: @Patrick "The reason for this is because the term "Mathematica" used to refer both to the software and to the language." Odd, given the Wolfram Research's usage reflected in e.g. Wikipedia https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mathematica which says Mathematica is the program and the language is Wolfram Language. "should probably read "What's your Wolfram System/Language question?" Aha. Thanks.

Comment: @Patrick Sorry I now realise that your "used" == "was used" not "is used". So, it did accord... before it didn't :-)

Answer (score 4):

Maybe my font size settings result in a truncated message but for me the subject bar reads:

> What's your Mathematica question? Be specific.

One may interpret **Mathematica** as the *name of this site* rather than the product.  Even if one does not however I think this provides a useful perspective on the scope of this site; it *is* about *Mathematica* (the product) and the other technologies by relation.  For example (stand-alone) Wolfram|Alpha is off-topic because it is not a close enough relation.

Comment: The second sentence comes from screen right. I have added a screenshot. "One may interpret Mathematica as the name of this site rather than the product" Somewhat ironic in this context of "Be specific" :-)

Comment: @ChrisJJ Thanks for the screen-shot.  Somehow I missed that text to the right.  I concede the irony.  I hold fast the second aspect however; *Mathematica*-the-software is the cornerstone of this site, and all valid questions are "about" it in one way or another.

Comment: "Mathematica-the-software ... all valid questions are "about" it in one way or another." I think you'd concede not, on e.g. http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/89532/how-can-i-prevent-shift-enter-moving-the-editing-cursor . I can see the frequency of this case will only increase.